# Android: toggling button (allowing multiple clicks)

Tags: java, android, if-statement, toggle, android-camera

I have a button that "supposedly" toggles between different if statements, but I'm not getting it correctly. The button is supposed to go through different camera flash states (ON/AUTO/OFF/TORCH) but it only goes through one of the states and then not go through the rest. Is the button correct? or is there a different toggle button?

```
   //Flash Button
    final Button flashButton = (Button) findViewById(id.camera_flash);
    flashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("Off");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE OFF");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera=null;
                flashButton.setText("TORCH");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE TORCH");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("ON");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE ON");

            }else if(p.getFlashMode() == android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH){
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE AUTO");

            }else{
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
                mCamera.setParameters(p);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                flashButton.setText("AUTO");
                Log.e("Torch","MODE AUTO");

            }           
        }
```

So basically, it only goes to the `FLASH_MODE_AUTO` and then the button doesn't work anymore. Is my if statements even correct? Thanks in advance!

UPDATED :

This is within in my onCreate(). Not sure if that will help?

Comment: @AnkitAwasthi for some reason, its not catching through the if statements. I'm log checking and to see what `p.getFlashMode()` is and what `android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)` is, but even if they do equal `==` each other, it doesn't go into that if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if that would help , but try using "equals(String)" instead of "==" for all of the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You have some of your text the wrong way round. For instance you test for FLASH_MODE_AUTO then setText to "ON". You test for FLASH_MODE_TORCH then set text to "AUTO". You might want to clear this up before continuing. Then trace the program as it executes.

Comment: Its supposed to be like this, because if I press the button again, it'll check if its in AUTO, if its in AUTO already then it should go to a different state...